# Setting Environment Variables for execve in shellcode-style Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, environment-variables, shellcode, execve

I am trying to write assembly code (x86 32-bit) to run a shell, I need to pass 3 environment variables to the shell, named xca1, xca2 and xca3, via the stack:

```
section .text
  global _start
    _start:
      xor eax, eax       

      ; Push "/bin/sh"
      push eax
      push "//sh"
      push "/bin"
      mov ebx, esp
      
      ; Push env vars
      push eax
      push "1234"
      push "="
      push "cccc"
      mov esi, esp

      push eax            
      push "5678"
      push "="
      push "bbbb"
      push esi      
      mov esi, esp 

      push eax            
      push "1234"
      push "="    
      push "aaaa"
      push esi            
      mov esi, esp

      ; Construct argv[]
      push eax            ; Null terminator for argv[1]
      push ebx            ; Pointer to "/bin//sh" for argv[0]
      mov ecx, esp        ; argv[] starts here

      ; Call execve()
      mov al, 0x0b        ; Syscall number for execve
      int 0x80            ; Invoke the system call
```

The code is assembled, linked and executes on Ubuntu 32-bit with no problem, and it opens a `/bin/sh` shell, however, when I run the `env` command, the 3 variables I defined do not appear. I can only see the `PWD` environment variable.

Any clue why this is happening??

Comment: Environment needs to be an array too. It's unclear what you are even doing, looks like strings intermixed with pointers.

Comment: I am pretty new to assembly, so excuse my ignorance

Comment: I am surprised it even works as much as you say it does, it should return `-EFAULT` and it does for me.

Comment: It does run, here you go:
```socrat@ubuntu:/shared_vm$ nasm -f elf32 labsh_env.asm -o labsh_env.o && ld -m elf_i386 -o labsh_env labsh_env.o && ./labsh_env```
```$ env```
```PWD=/shared_vm
```

Comment: @Jester: On my system it makes an `execve` system call with a NULL pointer for the environment, which Linux allows as equivalent to a zero-length array (pointer-to-NULL).  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#VERSIONS documents this but warns it's not portable to other OSes.  It succeeds, launching a shell.  `strace` output: `execve("/bin//sh", ["/bin//sh"], NULL)  = 0` ...  (I built this in a static 32-bit executable as the OP did, so envp=EDX=0 on process startup and this code doesn't do anything to change that.)

Comment: @Jester: But yes if you add code to try to use this alternating pointer and string stuff on the stack, like `push esi` / `mov edx, esi`, I also get `-EFAULT`.

Comment: Ah, I need `-no-pie` otherwise `edx` ends up being non-zero. I did build using `gcc` before the exact command was posted.